Where's the Errata for Epic Inspiration?
Epic Inspiration feat in 3.0 vs 3.5
The original text for Epic Inspiration (from Epic Level Handbook) is for a 3.0 bard whose inspire courage bonus doesn't progress with level (unlike in 3.5). It reads:

Benefit: All bonuses granted by your bardic music inspiration abilities are doubled. For example, your inspire courage ability now grants a +4 morale bonus on saving throws against charm and fear effects and a +2 morale bonus on attack and damage rolls; your inspire competence now grants a +4 competence bonus on skill checks; and your inspire greatness ability now grant +4d10 Hit Dice, a +4 bonus on attack, and a +2 competence bonus on Fortitude save.
Special:
You can gain this feat multiple times. Its effects stack. Remember that two doublings equals a tripling, and so forth.

The various SRD websites (d20srd, dndwiki, etc) have what looks to be a 3.5 updated text for the feat that reads:

Benefit: All competence bonuses, dodge bonuses, and morale bonuses granted by your bardic music ability increase by +1. If you have the inspire greatness bardic music ability, it grants one additional bonus HD.
Special:
You can gain this feat multiple times. Its effects stack.

My question is: where did this update come from?
As far as I know, the update means they used some errata file to update the rule, but I see no update to the feat in the official Epic Level Handbook errata pdf, and I can't find any updated version of it in any other book. I can see how the original text effectively works out to something like a +1 bonus per instance of the feat in 3.0, and so the 3.5 update above makes sense, but I can't find any original source showing the update seen on the SRD websites. Does anyone know if an official update actually exists, and if so, where to find it?

This update was published on Wizards’ website, in two of several PDFs that can be found on archive.org here. This particular entry is in both “D&D v.3.5 Accessory Update booklet” and “Epic Level Handbook update.” On some level, these are not considered “errata,” but rather part of the update to the “v.3.5 revised edition” of D&D.

Thanks for your knowledge as always, I didn't even know these existed! And yes, I take your point about these not being errata.
